# Alternative to numpy's linalg.eig?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pca

I have written a simple PCA code that calculates the covariance matrix and then uses `linalg.eig` on that covariance matrix to find the principal components. When I use scikit's PCA for three principal components I get almost the equivalent result. My PCA function outputs the third column of transformed data with flipped signs to what scikit's PCA function does. Now I think there is a higher probability that scikit's built-in PCA is correct than to assume that my code is correct. I have noticed that the third principal component/eigenvector has flipped signs in my case. So if scikit's third eigenvector is `(a,-b,-c,-d)` then mine is `(-a,b,c,d)`. I might a bit shabby in my linear algebra, but I assume those are different results. The way I arrive at my eigenvectors is by computing the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of the covariance matrix using `linalg.eig`. I would gladly try to find eigenvectors by hand, but doing that for a `4x4` matrix (I am using iris data set) is not fun.

Iris data set has 4 dimensions, so at most I can run PCA for 4 components. When I run for one component, the results are equivalent. When I run for 2, also equivalent. For three, as I said, my function outputs flipped signs in the third column. When I run for four, again signs are flipped in the third column and all other columns are fine. I am afraid I cannot provide the code for this. This is a project, kind of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is desired behaviour, even stated in the documentation of sklearn's PCA

> Due to implementation subtleties of the Singular Value Decomposition (SVD), which is used in this implementation, running fit twice on the same matrix **can lead to principal components with signs flipped** (change in direction). For this reason, it is important to always use the same estimator object to transform data in a consistent fashion.

and quite obviously correct from mathematical perspective, as if v is eigenvector of A then

```
Av = kv
```

thus also

```
A(-v) = -(Av) = -(kv) = k(-v)
```

Answer (score 1):

> So if scikit's third eigenvector is `(a,-b,-c,-d)` then mine is `(-a,b,c,d)`.

That's completely normal. If `v` is an eigenvector of a matrix, then `-v` is an eigenvector with the same eigenvalue.

Comment: Oh. That's why I said my linear algebra is shabby. In such a case the results are equivalent. This was impacting my 3d scatter plot. But now I will just flip the third column I suppose